# Subview hidden on dragging it outside the scroll view(which is the parent view) and appeared after being dropped into another view.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to implement a drag and drop functionality. When I am dragging the subview out of the scroll view which is the parent view, the subview gets hidden once it is dragged outside the scroll view's frame. It reappears after I drop it in the other frame. How do I make the subview visible while dragging form the scroll view to the other view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the **clipsToBounds** property of the superview to **YES**.

Comment: I set the clipsToBound property of the scrollview to Yes as you suggested but the problem still persists.

Comment: if you want display any subView outside of its ParentView than you need set  clipsToBounds property YES.

Comment: -1 great follow up @freelancer can you provide a little more details or example for how to use clipsToBounds? perhaps a hierarchy design description?